# postgres how to drop all the table in a schema through command

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4

I use postgresql and I need to drop all the tables which are present in the schema. How can I delete from command prompt.

Answer (score 26):

You want to use the `CASCADE` option of `DROP SCHEMA`. From [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/sql-dropschema.html):

> `CASCADE`  - Automatically drop objects (tables, functions, etc.) that are
>   contained in the schema, **and in turn all objects that depend on those
>   objects**

BE CAREFUL - emphasis above mine.

Obviously you'll need to recreate the schema afterwards.

To just drop all tables in the current schema, you can use this script:

```
DO $$ DECLARE
    tabname RECORD;
BEGIN
    FOR tabname IN (SELECT tablename 
                    FROM pg_tables 
                    WHERE schemaname = current_schema()) 
LOOP
    EXECUTE 'DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ' || quote_ident(tabname.tablename) || ' CASCADE';
END LOOP;
END $$;
```

Change `WHERE schemaname = current_schema()` if you want to drop all of the tables in a different schema.

Comment: when i use  DROP SCHEMA schemaname CASCADE; am getting error
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "DROP"
LINE 2: DROP Schema

Comment: `LINE 2`? What's on line 1?

Comment: actually i need to drop all the tables and its dependent object. but it should not delete procedure and all..

Comment: but when i use the drop schema command it delete the schema also. in my case schema should be exists

Comment: @asalthangam answer updated

Comment: Sometimes you can't delete all tables because they depend on extensions or whatever. If you want to skip them, then update script as follows: `LOOP 
  BEGIN
      EXECUTE 'DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ' || quote_ident(tabname.tablename) || ' CASCADE';
  EXCEPTION when others then 
      raise notice 'skipping %',quote_ident(tabname.tablename);
  END; 
END LOOP;`

Answer (score 7):

```
yourdb=# DROP SCHEMA *schema_name* CASCADE;
```

(works, just tested with Postgresql 9.6.3, might not work with previous releases)

Answer (score 3):

@Techno Savvy

Drop tables using postgres syntax:

```
select '-- drop table ' || tablename || ' cascade;' from pg_tables 
where tablename not like 'pg%' and tablename not like 'sql%';
```

Copy the resulting text into a sql script or psql terminal.  Note that the commands are commented out.

Comment: The question was about dropping tables in a specific schema, I think.

Answer (score -2):

If you just want a really simple way to do this.. Heres a script I have used in the past

```
select 'drop table '||table_name||' cascade constraints;' from user_tables;
```

This will print out a series of drop commands for all tables in the schema. Spool the result of this query and execute it.

Likewise if you want to clear more than tables you can edit the following to suit your needs

```
select 'drop '||object_type||' '|| object_name || ';' from user_objects where object_type in ('VIEW','PACKAGE','SEQUENCE', 'PROCEDURE', 'FUNCTION', 'INDEX')
```

Source:https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=614090

Comment: The question is Postgres, not Oracle.